# Prove the non-orientability of a vector bundle using the first Stiefel-Whitney class $w_1 \neq 0$

Tags: differential-topology, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

Question:

How to compute the first Stiefel-Whitney class $w_1$ of the following vector bundle? Or Prove it is $w_1\neq 0$.

- The base space is a torus $T^2$
- The fiber is locally $\mathbb{R}$
- The line bundle is non-trivial: along the each loop (no matter toroidal or poloidal), the fiber bundle is a mobius strip.

What I know:

- The first Stiefel-Whitney class of a fiber bundle $E$ is $w_1(E)\in H^1(M;\mathbb{Z}_2)$, where $M$ is the base space.
- The computing of $H^1(T^2;\mathbb{Z}_2)$

  $\delta^0(p^*)=0$

  $\delta(a^*,b^*,c^*)=（u^*,v^*）[ \begin{matrix}1 & 1 & 1\\1 & 1 & 1 \end{matrix}]$

  $im\delta^0=0$

  $ker\delta^1=\mathbb{Z}_2[a^*+b^*]\oplus \mathbb{Z}_2[b^*+c^*]$

  $H^1(T^2)=ker \delta^1/im\delta^0=\mathbb{Z_2}[a^*+b^*]\oplus\mathbb{Z_2}[b^*+c^*]$

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $L \to S^1\times S^1$ denote the line bundle you describe.

The restriction of $L$ to $S^1\times\{p\}$ is non-trivial, so $L$ is non-trivial and hence $w_1(L) \neq 0$ since real line bundles are classified up to isomorphism by their first Stiefel-Whitney class. Identifying $w_1(L) \in H^1(S^1\times S^1; \mathbb{Z}_2)$ requires some more work.

For each $p \in S^1$ we have inclusions $i_p : S^1 \to S^1\times S^1$ and $j_p : S^1 \to S^1\times S^1$ given by $i_p(q) = (q, p)$ and $j_p(q) = (p, q)$ respectively. We also have projections $\pi_i : S^1\times S^1 \to S^1$ for $i = 1, 2$ where $\pi_i(a_1, a_2) = a_i$. Note that $\pi_1\circ i_p = \operatorname{id}_{S^1}$ and $\pi_2\circ j_p = \operatorname{id}_{S^1}$. On the other hand, $\pi_2\circ i_p = c_p$ and $\pi_1\circ j_p = c_p$ where $c_p : S^1\to S^1$ is the constant map given by $c_p(q) = p$.

Let $\gamma \to S^1$ denote the non-trivial real line bundle on $S^1$. From your description of $L$, we have $i_p^*L \cong \gamma$ and $j_p^*L \cong \gamma$.

By the Künneth theorem, there is an isomorphism

\begin{align*}
H^1(S^1; \mathbb{Z}_2)\oplus H^1(S^1; \mathbb{Z}_2) &\to H^1(S^1\times S^1; \mathbb{Z}_2)\\
(\alpha, \beta) &\mapsto \pi_1^*\alpha + \pi_2^*\beta.
\end{align*}

In particular, $w_1(L) \in H^1(S^1\times S^1; \mathbb{Z}_2)$ is of the form $\pi_1^*\alpha + \pi_2^*\beta$ for some $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Now note that

\begin{align*}
w_1(L) &= \pi_1^*\alpha + \pi_2^*\beta\\
i_p^*w_1(L) &= i_p^*\pi_1^*\alpha + i_p^*\pi_2^*\beta\\
w_1(i_p^*L) &= (\pi_1\circ i_p)^*\alpha + (\pi_2\circ i_p)^*\beta\\
w_1(\gamma) &= \operatorname{id}_{S^1}^*\alpha + c_p^*\beta\\
w_1(\gamma) &= \alpha.
\end{align*}

Likewise

\begin{align*}
w_1(L) &= \pi_1^*\alpha + \pi_2^*\beta\\
j_p^*w_1(L) &= j_p^*\pi_1^*\alpha + j_p^*\pi_2^*\beta\\
w_1(j_p^*L) &= (\pi_1\circ j_p)^*\alpha + (\pi_2\circ j_p)^*\beta\\
w_1(\gamma) &= c_p^*\alpha + \operatorname{id}_{S^1}^*\beta\\
w_1(\gamma) &= \beta.
\end{align*}

Therefore

$$w_1(L) = \pi_1^*\alpha + \pi_2^*\beta = \pi_1^*w_1(\gamma) + \pi_2^*w_1(\gamma).$$

Now that we have identified $w_1(L)$ and real line bundles are classified up to isomorphism by their first Stiefel-Whitney class, we can find an expression for $L$. Since

$$w_1(L) = \pi_1^*w_1(\gamma) + \pi_2^*w_1(\gamma) = w_1(\pi_1^*\gamma) + w_1(\pi_2^*\gamma) = w_1(\pi_1^*\gamma\otimes\pi_2^*\gamma),$$

we see that $L \cong \pi_1^*\gamma\otimes\pi_2^*\gamma$. For a proof of the last equality above, see the Lemma in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3133147/39599).

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for the answer. Does $i_p^*$ and $\pi_i^*$ mean pullbuck? $i_p^*L$ means $i_p^*(L)$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Hi Michael, sorry that I'm a very beginner. There are some parts that I didn't follow: (i) About the Kunneth theorem, I read that mostly it is described as f: $H^1(X;\mathbb{Z_2})\otimes H^1(Y;\mathbb{Z_2}) \rightarrow H^1(X\times Y;\mathbb{Z_2})$ , why in our case, it is $\oplus$ instead of $\otimes$?   (ii) Why $i_p^* w_1(L)=w_1(i_p^*L)$?   (iii) I have some difficulties deducing the explicit function $\pi_1^*$ to calculate $\pi_1^*w_1(\gamma)$ at the end. Could you help me with these doubts?

Comment: (iv) How could we get $(\alpha,\beta) \mapsto \pi_1^*\alpha +  \pi_2^*\beta $.  Thanks for the help : )

Comment: (i) What you wrote about $f$ is incorrect. The Künneth theorem tells you that $H^*(X; \mathbb{Z}_2)\otimes H^*(Y;\mathbb{Z}_2) \cong H^*(X\times Y; \mathbb{Z}_2)$, so $\bigoplus_{i+j=k}H^i(X;\mathbb{Z}_2)\otimes H^j(Y; \mathbb{Z}_2) \cong H^k(X\times Y; \mathbb{Z}_2)$. Now if $X$ and $Y$ are path-connected, $$H^1(X\times Y; \mathbb{Z}_2) \cong H^1(X;\mathbb{Z}_2)\otimes H^0(Y;\mathbb{Z}_2)\oplus H^0(X;\mathbb{Z}_2)\otimes H^1(Y;\mathbb{Z}_2) \cong$$ $$H^1(X;\mathbb{Z}_2)\otimes\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2\otimes H^1(Y;\mathbb{Z}_2) \cong H^1(X;\mathbb{Z}_2)\oplus H^1(Y;\mathbb{Z}_2).$$

Comment: (ii) This is a property of Stiefel-Whitney classes: $w_i(f^*E) = f^*w_i(E)$. (iii) I don't know what you mean by this. (iv) This follows from the explicit isomorphism in the Künneth Theorem. If you want more details, you can read the proof in Section 3.2 of Hatcher's [*Algebraic Topology*](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf) for example.

Comment: It is very helpful and clear. (iii) We have $w_1(L)=\pi_1^*w_1(\gamma)+\pi_2^*w_1(\gamma)$. Since $\gamma$ is non-trivial, $w_1(\gamma)=1$. I don't know how to compute the final result $w_1(L)$. I suppose it should be $w_1(L)=(1,1)\in \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: Under the isomorphism $H^1(S^1\times S^1; \mathbb{Z}_2) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$ described in my answer, $w_1(L)$ maps to $(1, 1)$ as you indicate.