# Relation between the first Pontryagin class $p_1$ and the first Stiefel Whitney class $w_1$ as a tangential structure of manifold M

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, characteristic-classes

In Characteristic Class, let us define tangential structure of manifold M such as tangent bundle TM.

0. Is there a difference between the Stiefel Whitney class $w_1 =0$ and the first Stiefel Whitney class $w_1=\delta \gamma$ is trivialized? Which case implies the manifold M is oriented?
1. Is the first Pontryagin class $p_1$ defined only when the manifold is oriented (the first Stiefel Whitney class $w_1$ is zero)?
2. When the first Pontryagin class $p_1$ can be trivialized as the $p_1$ structure,  is the first Stiefel Whitney class $w_1$ also trivialized thus the manifold is oriented?

If possible, the pedagogical answer will be nice.

Comment: for question 0, if the cochain representing $w_1$ is a coboundary, then it is cohomologous to the trivial cohomology class, and therefore $w_1=0$, so I don't see how orientation is playing a role here, but maybe I misunderstood your question in some way. For question 1, Pontrjagin class is defined for real vector bundles, not just oriented ones.

Comment: I mean "Which case implies the manifold M is oriented?" Usually we say that the $w_1=0$ means the manifold is orientable. Maybe $w_1=0$ means the manifold is orientable; s 1= is trivialized with different  means different orientation thus different oriented manifold of the same orientable manifolds? (Thanks!)

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4439811/prove-the-non-orientability-of-a-vector-bundle-using-the-first-stiefel-whitney-c?rq=1